# Android. Как организовать комментарии под новостью?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Доброго времени суток.
На данный момент занимаюсь разработкой клиента для соц.сети и столкнулся с такой сложностью.

Есть NestedScrollView для отображения, так сказать, аватарки новости и текста новости под ней. Соответственно, когда мы прокручиваем текст вниз, то аватарка скрывается в AppBar. В приложениях вк, пикабу и т.п. комментарии подгружаются во время работы программы и потом отображаются. Собственно, в чем суть вопроса.

NestedScrollView имеет в себе вертикальную прокрутку. Я думал использовать RecyclerView и заполнять его комментариями, но у него тоже есть вертикальная прокрутка. На сколько я знаю, андроид не позволяет помещать в одну вью с прокруткой другую с прокруткой. Как решить эту задачу и как решают ее в других клиентах? Расскажите пожалуйста. На данный момент сделал добавление комментариев в LinearLayout, который инклудом добавляется в NestedScrollView, но при большом кол-ве комментов будут проблемы с памятью, на сколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто - используйте только RecyclerView. В нём вам нужны минимум 2 типа ячеек - 1 для новости, 2 - для комментов. Т.е. в первую ячейку поместите всё, что не комменты, во все остальные - комменты.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, такой вариант уже рассматривался. Но есть одна загвоздка, разве можно заменить NestedScrollView на RecyclerView без потери изображения, выезжающего из AppBar'а ??

Comment: @ДенисТараненко, да, можно, все так и делают

Comment: я вас понял. Спасибо вам огромное за помощь.